# C# WPF: Insert Shape Into TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf

I am looking to insert a coloured square (with a border) into a `TextBlock` in WPF. The colour of the square needs to be set dynamically, and so ideally this should happen in the code-behind, not XAML.

I'm guessing the best way to do this is with a `InlineUIContainer`, but I can't work out how to position a `Rectangle` such that it aligns with the text, and is sized appropriately to the font size.

So far I have:

```
Color myColor = GetMyColor();

TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
textBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run("My color: "));

// Attempt with a Canvas and Rectangle
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
canvas.Children.Add(new Rectangle() { Height = 6, Width = 6, Fill = new SolidColorBrush(color.Value) });

textBlock.Inlines.Add(new InlineUIContainer(canvas));

// Hacky version that looks terrible
textBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run("  ") { Background = new SolidColorBrush(myColor) });
```

The problem here is that the `Rectangle` is created from the text baseline, hanging down. I would like it to be vertically centred relative to the text, square (i.e. aspect ratio of 1), and ideally automatically sized to the font size.

I'd wondered if a `Viewbox` was somehow useful, or some combination of `VerticalAlignment` properties, but I couldn't make them work. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to do it in code behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `ContentControl` and a `DataTemplate`.
A `UserControl` or custom `Control` or `ContentControl` is also a good solution, especially if you like to add a behavior.

The following example uses a `ContentControl` and a `DataTemplate` to display a centered `Rectangle` next to a text, where the shape's color and the text are dynamic values. The size of the shape is relative to the `FontSize` applied to the `ContentControl`.
The final size of the shape can be adjusted by setting a `Margin` on the `Viewbox` or by attaching a `IValueConverter` to the `Height` binding of the `Viewbox`:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataModelTemplate" 
                  DataType="{x:Type DataModel}">
      <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl}, Path=HorizontalContentAlignment}">
        <TextBlock x:Name="TextLabel"
                   FontSize="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl}, Path=FontSize}"
                   Text="{Binding TextValue}"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <Viewbox Height="{Binding ElementName=TextLabel, Path=ActualHeight}"
                 Margin="8"
                 Stretch="Uniform">
          <Rectangle Width="10"
                     Height="10"
                     Fill="{Binding Color}" />
        </Viewbox>
      </DockPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>

  <StackPanel>
    <ContentControl x:Name="TextControl1"
                    ContentTemplate="{StaticResource DataModelTemplate}"
                    FontSize="50" />
    <ContentControl x:Name="TextControl2"
                    ContentTemplate="{StaticResource DataModelTemplate}"
                    FontSize="20" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  
    this.TextControl1.Content = new DataModel("@Test 1", Brushes.Yellow);
    this.TextControl2.Content = new DataModel("@Test 2", Brushes.Red);
  }
}
```

**DataModel.cs**

```cs
class DataModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public DataModel(string textValue, Brush color) 
  {
    this.TextValue = textValue;
    this.Color = color;
  }

  public string TextValue { get; }
  public Brush Color { get; }
}
```

Comment: You may be horrified at my lack of XAML, but simply stealing the DockPanel/Viewbox combination from here has solved my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the size of square you want, you could try using unicode characters 0x25A0 or 0x25AA.

Here's an example defined in Xaml, but you could achieve the same effect in code behind too.

```
<TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe UI">
    <Run Text="ABC" />
    <Run Foreground="Red" Text="&#x25a0;" />
    <Run Foreground="Green" Text="&#x25aa;" />
</TextBlock>

<TextBlock FontFamily="Tahoma">
    <Run Text="ABC" />
    <Run Foreground="Red" Text="&#x25a0;" />
    <Run Foreground="Green" Text="&#x25aa;" />
</TextBlock>
```

[image]

Note that different font families render these characters with different proportion compared to the hight of the regular letters.

Comment: This could be a workaround. But I was hoping to be able to extend things to draw more complex shapes, to show missing data or similar. Thanks for the suggestion!